# Как анализируются строки наподобии LESS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пример:

```
.class01 {
    .class02 { 
        color:#000; 
    }
}
```

Какие есть варианты анализаторов этого примера. На ум приходит только с помощью регулярок с низу вверх.
Использование готовых библиотек не предлагать. Конечная цель создать дерево похожее на представленное ниже

```
[{
    name: '.class01', 
    data: '',
    links: [{
        name: '.class02',
        data: 'color:#000;',
        links: []
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Переводя на язык Computer Science: из строки с исходным кодом на LESS вы хотите сделать абстрактное синтаксическое дерево, в котором можно выделить селекторы секций, их непосредственные свойства и вложенные секции. Похоже?

Comment: Поищите статейки про синтаксические парсеры. Часто попадается ANTLR - инструмент для генерации парсеров структурированного текста. Даже если он не нужен, то всё равно есть шансы ознакомится с теорией этого дела

Comment: LESS выбран как пример. 
@D-side
Да, похоже.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Шаг 1. Производим *лексический анализ*, разбивая исходный текст на **токены**. Получим массив наподобие:

```
'.class01', '{', '.class02', '{', 'color', ':', '#000', ';', '}', '}'
```

Шаг 2. Производим *синтаксический анализ*, составляя иерархическую структуру на основе полученного массива. В данном примере открывающая фигурная скобка есть начало блока содержимого, а закрывающая, соответственно, его конец. Таким образом структура примет, примерно такой вид:

```
var tree = {
  '.class01': {
    '.class02': { 
      color: '#000' 
    }
  }
};
```

Шаг 3. На основе полученных данных составляем структуру под наши нужды.

P.S. Для построения структуры исходного текста, про использование *регулярных выражений* можете забыть, так как в них сложно следить за парностью открывающих/закрывающих скобок.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Но как следить за парностью с низу вверх, с помощью регулярок, я приблизительно вижу. А с верху вниз я так понимаю регулярки не позволят.
Пример. Находим самый глубокое вложение, запоминаем в массив, а в тексте заменяем его на @N(где N номер в массиве) и т.д. 
Вторым шагом проводим анализ заменяя текстовые ссылки на настоящии

Comment: @user2245887 ну вот простой пример: `.class1:before { content: '{{{{{}}}}}}}' }` который доставит лишние хлопоты при использовании регулярных выражений для данной цели.

Comment: Про парсинг html, css http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/