# Как создать синтаксический анализатор кода на C++?

Tags: синтаксический-анализ

Мне нужно создать синтаксический анализатор на основе таких алгоритмов: 
1) Определение левсем в тексте кода
2) Создание словаря ключевых слов
3) Поиск синтаксических ошибок в ключевых словах
4) Поиск синтаксических ошибок в символах( роздилительные знаки,скобки и т.д.)

Если не знаите реализации буду рад за любую информацию)

Comment: Первые шаги могут быть наподобие https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521754/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B8-less/521762#521762

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется именно с нуля написать, то стоит начать с чтения "[книги дракона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)". В этой книге (уже в первых главах) есть ответы на все вопросы, с исходным кодом и примерами. Но только для с/c++ лучше вначале прогнать текст через препроцессор - так немножко упростите себе задачу (или написать свой).

Но можно пойти проще - взять готовый анализатор - [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/devinfo/), посмотреть, как он устроен, а дальше либо написать свой, либо "погнуть сорцы до нужной консистенции". А может быть, улучшить оригинальный cppcheck.